# $sce.trustAsHtml is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, uialertview

I have a alert that is as below:

```
$scope.addAlert('danger', $sce.trustAsHtml('Invalid Alias Name: Certain 
limitations apply to alias naming. <a href="http://google.com/">Please refer 
to the documentation</a>'));
```

and I am binding this to html page as :

```
 <uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" 
 close="closeAlert($index, alerts)" dismiss-on-timeout="2500">
            <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></span>
        </uib-alert>
```

As a result, 
**Actual output:**

```
    Error: Invalid Alias Name: Certain 
    limitations apply to alias naming. '<a href="http://google.com/">Please 
    refer to the documentation</a>'
```

**Expected Output:**
    Error: Invalid Alias Name: Certain 
        limitations apply to alias naming. '[Please 
        refer to the documentation](http://google.com/)'

Can anyone please help? I do not know what I am missing!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure that you have injected **ngSanitize** in your module?

Comment: yes, it is injected

Answer (score 1):

Your example should work, check for any errors in the console. Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.alerts = [];
  $scope.addAlert = function(type, msg) {
    $scope.alerts.push({
      "type": type,
      "msg": msg
    });
  }
  $scope.addAlert('danger', $sce.trustAsHtml('Invalid Alias Name: Certain limitations apply to alias naming. <a href="http://google.com/">Please refer  to the documentation</a>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-class="'alert alert-{{alert.type}}'">
    <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note on:

- Injection of `ngSanitize` module
- Injection of `$sce`
- Using `<div uib-alert` instead of `<uib-alert` (*optional*)
- Changing `type` to `ng-class` with the right syntax for bootstrap CSS

Comment: getting Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context:html ...

Comment: @PoojaThapa the `msg` that you are passing as a parameter is not a string (_text version of html_)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like the below code, also you can check this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sj83G5Vk0jPSg76nqsAY?p=preview) for your given sample scenario.

**Template:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
      <h4 ng-bind="alert.title"></h4>
      <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg | formatContent"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.alerts=[];
  $scope.addAlert=function(title, msg){
    $scope.alerts.push({title: title, msg: msg});
  }
  $scope.addAlert('danger', 'Invalid Alias Name: Certain limitations apply to alias naming. <a href="http://google.com/">Please referto the documentation</a>');
});

app.filter('formatContent', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(input){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
  }
}]);
```

I have Updated my answer to achieve it with filter as shown in the above code also check [this plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/sj83G5Vk0jPSg76nqsAY?p=preview) which is working with the filter implementation.

Comment: I have a separate AlertsFactory for the same which includes above method.

Comment: Or if you could suggest me another method to include the link within alert?

Comment: Do you get any console error in browser developer window?